# Kubernetes service not visible when Docker is initialized in Windows container mode

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, kubernetes-service

I'm testing the side-by-side Windows/Linux container experimental feature in Docker for Windows and all is going well.  I can create Linux containers while the system is set to use Windows containers.  I see my ReplicaSets, Services, Deployments, etc in the Kubernetes dashboard and all status indicators are green.  The issue, though, is that my external service endpoints don't seem to resolve to anything when Docker is set to Windows container mode.  The interesting thing, however, is that if I create all of my Kubernetes objects in Linux mode and then switch to Windows mode, I can still access all services and the Linux containers behind them.

Most of my Googling took me to errors with services and Kubernetes but this doesn't seem to be suffering from any errors that I can report.  Is there a configuration somewhere which must be set in order for this to work?  Or is this just a hazard of running the experimental features?

Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3

Docker Engine 18.09.2

Kubernetes 1.10.11

Answer (score 1):

just to confirm your thoughts about experimental features:

> Experimental features are not appropriate for production environments or workloads. They are meant to be sandbox experiments for new ideas. Some experimental features may become incorporated into upcoming stable releases, but others may be modified or pulled from subsequent Edge releases, and never released on Stable.

Please consider additional steps to resolve this issue:

> The Kubernetes client command, kubectl, is included and configured to connect to the local Kubernetes server. If you have kubectl already installed and pointing to some other environment, such as minikube or a GKE cluster, be sure to change context so that kubectl is pointing to docker-for-desktop

```
> kubectl config get-contexts
> kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop
```

If you installed kubectl by another method, and experience conflicts, remove it.

To enable **Kubernetes support** and install a standalone instance of Kubernetes running as a Docker container, **select Enable Kubernetes and click the Apply and restart button**.

**By default**, Kubernetes containers **are hidden** from commands like **docker service ls**, because managing them manually is not supported. To make them visible, select Show system containers (advanced) and click Apply and restart. Most users do not need this option.

Please verify also [System requirements](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues with Docker Windows. I realized we need to switch to linux by clicking on **windows tray right click docker** as below:

[image]

Please note, if your previous images are on windows, you need to run the same process after switching to linux and then continue with your Kubernetes kubectl